# Is there an alternative approach for cursor in my PL/SQL code?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
create or replace package body as p_company as

function f_insert(p_emp_no in emps.bs_emp%type, p_res out number) return number as

begin

delete from com
where com_empno = p_emp_no;

insert into com 
(...) select ... from v_com where no = p_emp_no;

end f_insert;

/* function f_update()
funtion f_validate()*/

function f_exe(p_type in varchar2, p_res out number) return number as

cursor crs_no is
select bs_emp
from emps
where bs_emp in (select s.emp_id from v_emp_det s where s.emp_type=p_type);

alt_crs crs_no%rowtype;

begin
p_res = 0;
open crs_no

loop

fetch crs_no into alt_crs
exit when crs_no%notfound;

f_insert(alt_crs.bs_emp, p_res);

/*f_update
f_validate*/

end loop;
close crs_no;

end f_exe;
end p_company;
```

/* In the same way, I have functions to f_update and f_validate(commented in code). They are called in function f_exe. To extract each bs_emp and call them in each function, is taking a long time, is there any alternative approach for this? */

Comment: I removed the [plsqldeveloper](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/plsqldeveloper/info) tag because it seems that you don't need a solution for [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/products/pl-sql-developer/) specifically. Please check the info about each tag before using it.

Answer (score 1):

Row-by-row processing is usually slow-by-slow.

What to do? Don't use a loop. Take cursor's query and apply it directly to `INSERT`:

```
insert into com (...) 
select ... 
from v_com v join emps e on e.bs_emp = v.no
             join v_emp_det s on s.emp_type = p_type;
```

---

If you're updating and inserting at the same time (seems so, as you're calling those two procedures from `f_exe`), you'd rather use `merge` (instead of separate `update` and `insert` procedures (or statements):

```
merge into com c
  using (select ...
         from v_com v join emps e on e.bs_emp = v.no
                      join v_emp_det s on s.emp_type = p_type
        ) x
  on (x.id = c.id)
when matched then update set
  c.name = x.name,
  c.address = x.address
when not matched then insert (id, name, address)
  values (x.id, x.name, x.address;
```

(I *fabricated* column names as you used `(...)` instead of them so there's no way I could guess them right).

---

Finally: why do you use **functions**? Are you really returning some value to the caller? Wouldn't **procedure(s)** be a more appropriate choice?

Comment: Yes, I am returning some value. 
Before inserting and updating, I have to delete the matched records. How can I add it to the code?

Comment: Run DELETE before INSERT or UPDATE or MERGE.

Comment: I have to use p_emp_no even in the log, how can I extract each p_emp_no and display the result?